# Movendo uma Div

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, front-end

Estou com um problema que não estou entendendo as soluções que estou procurando.

Sou iniciante na programação, com apenas 4 dias e estou tentando entender sobre movimentos das divs. Tentei mover as divs por display e position mas não consigo centralizar ela ao meio da tela.

Tentando de algumas maneiras, sua maioria apenas tentativa, e realizando algumas pesquisas não entendi bem como faria.

Vou deixar o código abaixo, e se alguém puder me ajudar, serei grato.

```css
* {
    font-family:'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
    background:linear-gradient(-45deg, #141f31, #19273c, #1d2f46, #223852);
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
.container {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width:800px;
    height:auto;
}
.container_tower {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    width:350px;
    height:300px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#0c131d;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:20px;
}
.container_tower h1 {
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}
.container_tower input {
    background-color:transparent;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
    /*Esse outline tira as bordas externa do input*/
    outline:0;
}
.container_tower input:hover {
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #ec3535;
}
.container_tower .submit button {
    padding:10px;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline:0;
}
.container_tower button:hover {
    border:1px solid #223852;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #00ffff;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Opening</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container_tower">
                <h1>Opening</h1>
                <form method="GET">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" autofocus/>
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
                </form>
                <di class="submit">
                <button>login</button>
                </di>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta e explicar com mais detalhes o que quer dizer com movimentos das divs? Acredito que queira posicionar elementos, mas posso estar enganado.

Comment: Centralizar verticalmente ou horizontalmente? Além disso, qual(is) div(s) aparece(m) para você sem centralizar? Rodei esse código no widget daqui do Stack Overflow, clicando no botão "Executar", e todos os elementos do formulário apareceram centralizados (exceto os placeholders das caixas de texto (isto é, o texto interno da caixa de texto que fica aparecendo enquanto ninguém digita nada), "Username" e "Password", que apareceram alinhados à esquerda).

Comment: Fala galera! Quando falo em movimentar as divs é como o Augusto falou, quero entender como posicioná-las. No meu navegador ela aparece toda bugada, ou seja, nada está centralizado. Até reinstalei o meu vscode, mas não tive sucesso. Não pensei em recriar até porque, preciso entender o que estou fazendo. Se puderem me indicar algum livro ou vídeo para que eu possa estudar melhor e dá próxima vez vir com uma questão mais concreta e clara, serei eternamente grato. PS: Sou novato me programação, mesmo que seja de estruturação de site, que é  o meu caso. Iniciei no html5 e css3. Curso.

Answer (score -3):

Olá, boa tarde! Tente colocar:
.container {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content: center;
max-width:800px;
height:auto;
margin: 170px auto;}